# preUpdate: know which fields have been modified (ManyToMany)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've a listener on preUpdate to execute an action if one of 2 specific attributes were edited.

For one of them, it's easy I use `$args->hasChangedField('public')`, but the second field is a ManyToMany relation, for the moment I've find it `$uow->getScheduledCollectionUpdates()` that return a linked collection. In this collection I want to control the field, and there is a very interesting attribute fot it: backRefFieldName. But there is no method to get it and do the control.

Maybe there is an other solution ?

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $strain = $args->getEntity();

    if (!$strain instanceof Strain) {
        return;
    }

    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    $authorizedUsersChanged = false;
    foreach ($uow->getScheduledCollectionUpdates() as $entityScheduledUpdates) {
        // I can't do it because the method: 'getBackRefFieldName()' doen't exists
        if ('authorizedUsers' === $entityScheduledUpdates->getBackRefFieldName()) {
            $authorizedUsersChanged = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($args->hasChangedField('public') || $authorizedUsersChanged) {
        dump('do something');
    }

    }

    return;
}
```

EDIT: Finally I do it, but if there is a better way, I'me interested

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $strain = $args->getEntity();

    if (!$strain instanceof Strain) {
        return;
    }

    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    $updateElasticsearch = false;

    if (true === $args->hasChangedField('public')) {
        $updateElasticsearch = true;
    } else {
        foreach ($uow->getScheduledCollectionUpdates() as $entityScheduledUpdates) {
            if ('authorizedUsers' === $entityScheduledUpdates->getMapping()['fieldName']) {
                $updateElasticsearch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (true === $updateElasticsearch) {
        // DO something
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Would this be helpful? http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ew0r/logging-field-changes-with-a-trigger-like-event-listener-for-auditing-purposes

Comment: Thx, I've try it with a doubt about the comparaison of 2 ArrayCollection, but apparently `$args->getOldValue()` and `$args->getNewValue()` don't work to get a ManyToMany attribute.

Comment: You should listen on `preUpdate` event for linked enities separately.